# C++98, but clang-tidy says use nullptr?

Tags: c++, clion, clang-tidy

I am using Clion and my project is set to C++98, but clang-tidy has suggestions to use nullptr instead of NULL.

Is there a clang-tidy setting somewhere in the IDE or is it something else?

Comment: You have to disable the `modernize-*` checks.  The purpose of all of these is to tell you how to upgrade to C++11 (and newer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know CLion specifically but that message is related to the `modernize-use-nullptr` check which is intended for upgrading old code to use C++11 features. (in this case avoiding inadvertently using the NULL macro in assignment to non-pointer variables since it expands to 0)

Disable that check if you want to keep your code in C++98.